# how to configured quartz data source using JNDI in tomcat

Tags: quartz-scheduler, tomcat9, quartz

I am using quartz 2.3.2 version. I want to configured quartz datasource using the JNDI.

following are the properties that we have to use for jndi configured but not sure how to add those properties inside server.xml and context.xml

```
org.quartz.dataSource.myOtherDS.jndiURL=jdbc/myDataSource
org.quartz.dataSource.myOtherDS.java.naming.factory.initial=com.evermind.server.rmi.RMIInitialContextFactory
org.quartz.dataSource.myOtherDS.java.naming.provider.url=ormi://localhost
org.quartz.dataSource.myOtherDS.java.naming.security.principal=admin
org.quartz.dataSource.myOtherDS.java.naming.security.credentials=123
```

I really apricate your valuable response.

Thanks